# Removing elements from multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how this works is that only 2 items can be inside div3 and div4 accordingly. so i am trying to remove items of the last position if it's more than 2 and is in div4. However, after removing it, i want to remove the last item from div3 as well if it's more than 2 too.

Javascript:

```
var divdrag32 = $("#div3").length;
var divdrag42 = $("#div4").length;

if (divdrag42 > 2 || div === "div4") {
   $("#div4").find("#drag1, #drag2")[2].remove();

  } else if (divdrag32 > 2 || div === "div3") {
      $("#div3").find("#drag1, #drag2")[2].remove();
  }
```

The code above, only removes div4's last position item. But it does not remove div3's last position item. The id with #drag1 and #drag2 are the item's id (the one im finding)

Comment: Is `divdrag40` supposed to be `divdrag42`, or ...?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs on the same page. Use classes instead.

Comment: duplicate IDs of the elements?

Comment: If you look at the amount of assistance (and effort) provided to you here and the variety of answers I would suggest it worthwhile to give either some feedback to allow people to help better or provide more details in your question

Answer (score 0):

Since you use an `if` followed by an `else if` the second `if` will only evaluate if the first `if` is false. So if divdrag42 is greater than two (or div = "div4") then you'll never get to evaluate if divdrag32 is greater than two. To change that just take out the word `else`.

If you have a lot of these divs then you can set up a separate function and pass parameters or a looping block. Maybe something like this - and pardon me - I haven't done jQuery in a while and I'm assuming your code works since you said it successfully removes the div in the first `if`:

```
function removeExtraDivs(elmntId) {
    var $thisElmnt = $("'" + "#" + elmntId + "'");
    if ($thisElmnt.length > 2 || div === elmntId) {
        $thisElmnt.find("#drag1, #drag2")[2].remove();
    }
}
removeExtraDivs("div4");
removeExtraDivs("div3");
```

And sorry - I'm not sure this line is correct

```
var $thisElmnt = $("'" + "#" + elmnt + "'");
```

basically you have to use that text passed through to build the selector - let me know if I have that wrong - maybe it has to be a couple of lines to build the selector then use it

Since you say it works I guess jQuery deals with the multiple IDs but those should be classes, so instead of

```
<div id="div4">...
```

use

```
<div class="dropHere">...
```

The reason this is being mentioned is that a .length on an ID selector should always be 1 as IDs are meant to be unique on the page.

You can then use the method mentioned by Andrey by selecting the items with:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dropHere")
```

Answer (score 0):

Grabs every div element and removes more than 2.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    //do something to each div like
    divs[i].find("#drag1, #drag2")[2].remove();
}
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please consider adding some details and explanation to support your answer in order to help others

Answer (score 0):

You have same id of elements in div3 and div4, so in JavaScript it will remove only first occurrence of given id because in DOM duplicate element ids are not allowed. You need to use different ids or you can use class instead of id.

```
var divdrag32 = $("#div3").length;
var divdrag42 = $("#div4").length;

if (divdrag42 > 2 || div === "div4") {
   $("#div4").find(".drag1, .drag2")[2].remove();

  } else if (divdrag32 > 2 || div === "div3") {
      $("#div3").find(".drag1, .drag2")[2].remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very concise but I think it's what you're looking for..

```js
$('.removerer').click(function() {
  $('.div3').children().each(function(i) {
    if(i > 1) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
  $('.div4').children().each(function(i) {
    if(i > 1) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
})

// loops through each child of div3 and div4, removing each child after the 2nd.
// onclick is used for demonstration purposes, if this is something you need on page load just replace the .click line with $(document ).ready(function() { ...
```

```css
.removerer {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: hsla(207, 100%, 50%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.removerer:hover {
  background-color: hsla(353, 100%, 50%, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div div1">
  <span>d1 item 1</span>
  <span>d1 item 2</span>
  <span>d1 item 3</span>
</div>
<div class="div div2">
  <span>d2 item 1</span>
  <span>d2 item 2</span>
  <span>d2 item 3</span>
  <span>d2 item 4</span>
</div>
<div class="div div3">
  <span>d3 item 1</span>
  <span>d3 item 2</span>
  <span>d3 item 3</span>
</div>
<div class="div div4">
  <span>d4 item 1</span>
  <span>d4 item 2</span>
  <span>d4 item 3</span>
  <span>d4 item 4</span>
</div>

<div class="removerer">
  click to remove all children greater than 2 in divs 3 and 4
</div>
<div class="">
  click run to reset
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/uhLqujhb/